# Why console.log is not working in this case? Openweathermap api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, openweathermap

I'm in the middle of a weather app project and cannot understand why the console.log on line 20 is not working below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var long;
  var lat;
  var temp;
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      long = position.coords.longitude;
      lat = position.coords.latitude;

      var api =
        "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" +
        lat +
        "&lon=" +
        long +
        "&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
      //console.log(api); 
      $("#data").html("latitude: " + lat + "<br>longitude: " + long);
      $.getJSON(api, function(json) {
        var kelvin = data.main.temp;
        console.log(kelvin);
        
       
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
}
.container{
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Weather App</h1>
    <div id="data">location</div>
    <div id="temperature">Temperature
      <span id="degrees" onclick="">DEGREES</span></div>
    <div class="weather">Weather icon</div>
    
  </div>
  
</body>
```

I want to fetch the Temperature from the openweathermap api, and i was testing the kelvin variable, but it shows nothing.

many thanks in advance,

Comment: Add a fail handler as well and see, if the request went though.

Comment: Your callback takes `json` as a parameter, but you're accessing `data.main.temp`.

Comment: Print something else along with your degrees for the sake of clarity of what the variable is in the console.  If you do: `console.log("Kelvin: "+kelvin);` it will tell you whether or not it is printing, but at the same time informing you the data was wrong?  Similarly, you should be able to see the result of your network request in the approperiate tab to see if it is fetching the data correctly.

Comment: Try starting your url with `http://`

Comment: @Fallenreaper cleaner syntax `console.log("Kelvin:", kelvin);`  The space will be added for you and if `kelvin` is an `object` or `array` it will print them properly instead of `[Object object]`

Comment: @JamesThorpe what should I use as a parameter in this case?

Comment: @Fallenreaper did that but still nothing on the console. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Bergi did that, still doesnt work.

Answer (score -2):

That's not how you call $.getJSON.  It's not even close.

First argument is a URL, which the string you are supplying is not, since a URL begins with a protocol, like "https://".

The second argument is the data, not a function, which is what you are supplying.

The *third* argument is where the success callback goes.

And do the print-out first thing, in case that dereference fails.

Comment: FWIW both the 2nd and 3rd arguments are optional - passing a callback function with no data is fine.

Comment: The data parameter is optional, you can pass the callback second just fine: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: @Bergi -- if you are in a position to check, does a string that doesn't starts with a protocol just get tacked on to the current BASE_URL, or what?

Comment: @Malvolio I believe it's interpreted as a relative path, yes, but haven't checked either. It's definitely not kosher though.